# Our Magento website show file log name like debug.log-20231106.gz, Where and how can I change it?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, log

I think normal, Magento doesn't change the file log every day like this.

https://prnt.sc/Fu2U8hDurkAs

Does anyone have experience with it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, this is a behavior related to the system (server) and not Magento.

Automated file compression can be achieved through various methods, such as using `logrotate` or adding a cron job.

It appears that your system might be running a custom cron job to automatically compress log files. By default, `logrotate` does not compress log files in the date format.

You can view all cron jobs by running `crontab -l` command.
The `.gz` file format is typically created by the `gzip` utility when it compresses a file or a directory. [The command](https://linuxize.com/post/gzip-command-in-linux/) is similar to this `gzip filename > filename.gz`

You can stop this behavior by removing its cron job from the crontab file. To do that, run the `crontab -e` command and then delete the line for the specific task.
You can read more about Crontab command examples at https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/crontab-command/

Comment: Thank you so much!